# Facebook Login: -canopenurl issue with facebook sdk?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to integrate Facebook Login in my IOS app. The error

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"

is suddenly started coming now. My info.plist has following entries

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key> 
<array>     
<string>fbauth2</string>    
<string>fbapi</string>  
<string>fb-messenger-api</string> 
<string>fbshareextension</string> 
<string>fbauth</string> 
</array>
```

and

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

It was working fine some time back. I tried to logout and login again but it won't login now.

P.S. I'm trying to login on ios simulator of xcode

**Edit :**
This is happening just in iphone 6 simulator, rest of the simulators are working fine.

Comment: What is the version of your Facebook SDK?

Comment: By the way, could it be because you have two extra spaces left and right to your keys values in between <key></key>?

Comment: how do i check sdk version? It's not because of the space. I wrote them just here. I'll correct it

Comment: `NSLog( @"%@", [FBSettings sdkVersion] );`

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm using swift and fb sdk does not have any class by the name FBSettings

Comment: This may be caused by few reasons, one is that your FacebookSDK version is quite old, if it fits you can just upgrade your SDK.

Comment: I would check this documentation first: https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Comment: FBSDKSettings.sdkVersion()

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. I had been using the FB SDK from 8/13. I switched to the updated version from 9/10. The file downloaded from their developer site is FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910.zip